# Changing the letters

Tags: java

Well i'm trying to get a String from user and change each letter to the String "enc" I have down here. So basically if the user input "hello" I want it to return back "xahhi". I am kind of lost and don't know what to do.

```
String userInput = input.nextLine();

String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String enc =     "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";

int stringLength = userInput.length();

for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    if (userInput.charAt(i) == letters.charAt(i)) {
        System.out.print(enc.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing it with a pen and paper yourself, and try to see what steps you take to do that exactly. Then find the methods in `String` that would do the same thing.

Comment: Use a StringBuilder to store the encoded characters, when you're done, use its toString method to get the String result

Comment: I don't know StringBuilder, I guess if I want to write this program I need to know it according to you. So i'll leave this alone and go learn that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you check this question plz? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001686/selections-and-loops-without-mathematical-or-assignment-operations-other-than/33001762#33001762

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is have a [`Map<Character,Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where key will be correct Character that in the String and the value should be Character that is encoded.

Then you query the Map for the encoding an generate you encoded string.

Code should look like :

```
Map<Character,Character> myEncodingMap = new HashMap<Character,Character>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Character ch : letters.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(myEncodingMap.get(ch)
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Wowwww I have no idea how you do this, Dude I just started java and I am not even close to learning these stuff. I just got more confused. Tnx tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use String methods only, you're close. However, you need to use two methods from the String class to finish this: `indexOf(char)` and `charAt(int)`.

`indexOf(char)` takes a character and returns the index of the first location it appears in the string. For example, if you have a string with contents `Hello World`, then `str.indexOf('l')` will return 2, which is the first index in the string that matches the given character.

`charAt(int)` takes an integer and returns the character in a string at the given index. For example, using the same string as above, calling `str.charAt(4)` will return 'o'.

Using these two methods can get you an index of one string which you can then use to reference the character of the other.

I'm not going to put the answer in your code (you should learn enough to be able to do it yourself), but I'll give you a skeleton of how I would do this using just the two methods above.

```
// The two strings used for encoding
String strNormal = "ABCDEF";
String strCode = "UVWXYZ";

// The example string that is input by the user
String input = "BED";

/*** NOTE: This only replaces the first letter of the input string ***/

// Get the first character of the input string
char originalChar = input.charAt(0);

// Get the index of of the corresponding character in the normal string
int searchIndex = strNormal.indexOf(originalChar);

// Get the corresponding character of the encoder string
char encodedChar = strCode.charAt(searchIndex);

// Print out the encoded letter
System.out.print(encodedChar);
```

Though this approach will work, there are some caveats. The biggest one is performance: Every time you call `indexOf` or `charAt`, Java loops through the entire string to find what you're looking for. This isn't a problem for small strings like you'll be dealing with, but imagine a string that's maybe 10,000 characters long... It's possible that you'd have to search every letter in that string 10,000 times! Not super efficient.

Comment: Thank you I'll see what i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that might be a little simpler if you are just starting out in programming. I have explained what each line does in the code so take a look and try to understand and expand on it! Let me know what you think or if you have any questions.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray(); //Just takes the String and puts it into a array of chars
        char[] enc = "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe".toCharArray();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner for user input

        System.out.println("enter phrase"); //prompts for user input
        String input = scan.next(); //Takes user input and stores it in String input

        for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++){
            char temp = input.charAt(i); //Stores the first Character of the entered phrase in a variable called temp.

            int tempNums = (new String(letters).indexOf(temp)); //takes the position in the first array of the first char entered and stores it.
            System.out.print(new String(enc).charAt(tempNums)); //prints out the values of the first character according to the second array.   
                }       
            }

        }
```

Comment: One problem, it wont read anything after a space, so if i enter hello hello it will only read the first hello.

Comment: Chance the scan.next() to scan.nextLine() and let me know how that works for you =). If you are still having problems id be glad to help out further.

Comment: It compiles but there is a error, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at f1.main(f1.java:21)

Comment: There are multiple ways to fix this but the easiest is to simply add a space to the end of each char array. For example i added a space after the last character of each array in which was was the "z" here. char[] letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ".toCharArray();

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this, Although you used a array i was looking for String only, But since i know whats going on now i will do the String by myself to see if i can do it.

Comment: No problem. Make a solid attempt and post if you need any help =).